# Nominate Questions or Answers to the "Hall of Fame".

Tags: feature-request

Something like [Useful Command-line Commands on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-command-line-commands-on-windows) or the infamous EA [answer on subnetting](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work/49836#49836)

I'm thinking a story or answer with enough nominations could be added to the hall-of-fame.  Perhaps the HOF questions or answers could be shown across the trilogy sites, NOT recycled to the homepage, etc...

This also doesn't necessarily have to be questions or answers with the highest votes.

Comment: @Farseeker, I've always wondered why such questions haven't been closed, or simply deleted as off-topic noise.

Comment: @John i think it got up to 3 close votes at one point, but that's about it.

Comment: Hmmm... Now that there are more 3K users perhaps we should have another crack at getting it closed. That's 2 votes so far...

Comment: Oo oo ooo it's @4 now ... common ONE MORE kind soul ... plleeeeaaassseee (i'm patching right now ... little loopy)

Comment: It was Jeff himself who cast the final vote. :)

Comment: Some of those questions make me very sad that I can't cast a normal user-vote.  Mod-hammering in those cases is *SO* not worth the fallout.

Comment: @John - I'm constantly clicking to clsoe that question, and typical, when it finally happens I missed and now I'm not listed in the close voters :( Oh well.

Comment: @Farseeker, that is unfortunate because I know how much you would like to be listed but at least it's finally closed (at least until some drongos re-open it).

Comment: @Farseeker  You can still vote to delete :)

Comment: @Zypher, I've never noticed the delete option before (my vote has been registered). Is that a 10K thing?

Comment: @John- ya, it's a 10k

Comment: I voted to delete. It now needs only 207 more delete votes to succeed! I would love to see the "Deleted By x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x...x" notice, except I don't think deleted questions get that...

Comment: Make that 206 delete votes needed....

Comment: 205 now. Why does it require so many votes? There are just not that many 10K users yet and probably won't be for another couple of years. Seems rather pointless even having an option that cannot be applied.

Answer (score 3):

I hear you.  Sometimes I see a post and I think, "AAAGH!  I want to point a big shining spotlight on this person and say:  LOOK!  Look what SF can do!!"  A working solution would have to address some issues:

- The popularity would garner a lot of "me, too!" upvotes that don't accurately reflect what an upvote is intended to accomplish.  The question would likely have to be locked/retired.
- Maybe the asker/answerer doesn't *want* the question to be locked, so it would only be fair to get the consent of both the lock/retire/HoF process even begins.

Even with just those two points, we've got either a bunch of new coding for the site, or we're asking someone to spend a bunch of (free) time to gather this all together.  The mantra of the site(s) could be said to be: the mob will decide.  As much fun as I think a HoF might be, it's somewhat opposed to the hands-off nature of the Multi-Trilogy...

I feel like sorting by upvotes is close enough for horseshoes.

Answer (score 2):

I dislike the once-per-day thing. In fact, I think they should be "retired" when they hit the HoF. Give them a separate page where people can still vote and add on to them, but for God's sake, please stop having EA's subnet/routing primer bump up to the top. :)

We all know it's there and appreciate it. And I have personally pointed dozens of people to it and even asked him for his permission to use it in training sessions that I run, but HoF questions don't need more answers or views. I do like the idea of giving them some special distinction, though.

Comment: I actually agree with you.  It was a suggestion, but I've changed my question to reflect the HOF not being recycled to the homepage.

Comment: But I love coming back and seeing my subnetting question on the front page!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Oh god I hate that example question.</strike>  my hated question removed :)

*If* something like that was to be implemented, I would really want one of the criteria to be the fact that the question adds value to the site's mission. For example The One True Subnetting question would be a good candidate. A discussion of server names .. uhg.

Comment: Edited my question to include EAs answer too.

Answer (score 2):

I could almost go along with this rather pointless idea but only if the question is Community Wiki. Such a listing would attract an artificially high number of visitors and would therefore attract an artificially high number of votes. This would result in a sever skewing of the rep system that in my mind would make it very near worthless.

One thing I most definitely would NOT support is cross posting HOF stuff. e.g. An extraordinary programming question is nothing more than yet another off-topic question on the other sites, HOF or not.

Comment: I meant more of a cross post onthe sidebar not into the main flow of questions and answers. I think it would serve as 'ads' if you will, for the other sites.

Comment: @GregD, I'm sure you know how most of us feel about ads, even pseudo ads. I for one don't care what they're selling, as I'm not here to read ads, even if they are for connected sites.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting by votes essentially accomplishes what you describe.  People nominated them with every up vote.